# any code conversion tool for converting borland c++ to visual studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, owl, borland-c++

I have a old windows application written in borland C++ 5.0. this uses the OWL library very much in it's code. this has to be ported to Visual studio 2005/2008 (C++ or C#). search in google shows lot of links but nothing quite concrete or useful. can anyone show the correct direction to start this? also share any pitfalls or best practices?

Answer (score 4):

this is going to be a painful process to do. you may end up re-writing the entire application. before that consider OWLNext in sourceforge.

PS: I don't have any experience in doing this.

Answer (score 4):

if you do not want to rewrite the entire application, your best bet is to migrate to OWLNext
(http://owlnext.sourceforge.net/). 
First step will be to still use Borland C++ 5.0x, but upgrade the project to use OWLNext instead of the old OWL libraries. 
After that, you can create a new VC++ project, add your sources there, build OWLNext for VC++ and start using it for further development.

Jogy